# IOS open full size another controller from container in previous controller

Tags: ios

I have created a sample app that contains a container in the first controller. There is button inside the controller from where I need to open a new Controller and also provide the back button on the second view controller. Issue is the second view controller takes the dimensions of the container in the first view controller. How to open the second view controller with full size? I am using the interface builder.

Comment: Are you trying to present 2d VC as modal view controller or you push it on navigation stack?

Comment: I am doing it through the interface builder in the storyboard